Why is toluene less acidic than cyclopentadiene?
There is a test question asking which of: butane,  toluene, cyclopropene and cyclopentadiene is most acidic. The answer is cyclopentadiene and gaining aromaticity is supposed to be the reason. Benzyl anion is still well delocalised and aromatic, though, so how is cyclopentadienyl better?

I don't understand the question in your post. I suppose this is a really contrived way of asking 'which one of these stabilizes a negative charge the best,' in which case I would go with (4) as well. Also, charged aromatic compounds are NOT more stable than neutral ones. They can stabilize the charge better than non-aromatic compounds, but no compound ever wants to remain charged.

@Sonder alright thank you for clearing my misconception.

I pretty much wrote this question from scratch. Tell if something isn't clear or not OK with you. BTW Here some more about this "stability" issue https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/51555/why-is-cyclopentadiene-more-stable-than-its-aromatic-counterpart-cyclopentadieny

@Mithoron that is OK, thank you for the edit. Please excuse me as this was my first post, will articulate it in a better manner next time onwards.

If you read this answer, you'd understand this:

Aromaticity is a very strong driving force so aromaticity wins out; Huckel's rule is more important than the number of resonance structures.

So, $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of cyclopentadiene is 18 (in DMSO) is more acidic due to gaining aromaticity in its conjugate base than that of toluene ($\approx$ 42; Ref. 1), conjugate base of which shows more resonance structures. Cyclopentadiene is even more acidic than that of indene molecule ($\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of indene is 20 in DMSO; Ref. 1) for the same reason, even if conjugate base of indene provides more resonance structures than that of toluene.
Also, if you want to compare some bond dissociation energies you may read Ref. 2 & 3, for instance. About the concept of Quasi-aromaticity, some interesting info can be achieved by reading Ref. 4.
References:

Frederick G. Bordwell, George E. Drucker, and Herbert E. Fried, "Acidities of carbon and nitrogen acids: the aromaticity of the cyclopentadienyl anion," J. Org. Chem. 1981, 46(3), 632–635 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1021/jo00316a032).
Donald F. McMillen and  David M. Golden, "Hydrocarbon Bond Dissociation Energies," Ann. Rev. Phys. Chem. 1982, 33, 493–532 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev.pc.33.100182.002425).
Stephen J. Blanksby and G. Barney Ellison, "Bond Dissociation Energies of Organic Molecules," Acc. Chem. Res. 2003, 36(4), 255–263 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1021/ar020230d).
Tadeusz M. Krygowski, Barbara Bankiewicz, Zbigniew Czarnocki, and Marcin Palusiak, “Quasi-aromaticity—what does it mean?” Tetrahedron 2015, 71(30), 4895–4908 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tet.2015.05.074).


Strictly speaking, you do not gain aromaticity when you deprotonate toluene (or for that matter 2,4,6-trinitrotoluene, whose electron-withdrawing nitro groups render it reactive towards aqueous sodium hydroxide). The parent toluene molecule already has an aromatic ring, and while delocalizing the negative charge onto this ring is energetically favorable it is less so than creating an aromatic ring out of a previously nonaromatic system.
We see a similar situation with cations. The benzyl cation is also stabilized by delocalizing its charge onto an aromatic ring, but benzyl chloride can't deliver its chloride moiety to precipitate silver chloride from a silver salt solution in sulfur dioxide. 3-chlorocyclopropene, which actually creates an aromatic ring through this reaction, can (this is a common homework problem in organic chemistry texts).
